# Configure Bluemix SSO service with BlueID/IBM ID authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

We are trying to leverage BlueID/IBM ID authentication for our application deployed on Bluemix node.js instance. Is it possible to configure the Bluemix SSO service with Blue ID (OpenID) authentication. Right now I see support for SAML, Cloud Directory and some social networks. But I am really interested to know if the SSO service has support to use Blue ID authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix Single Sign On does not currently support the standards for IBM ID login.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got a similar reply from the IBM ID team. I just happen to stumble up on this question after quite a while. I have a quick question: Will this be included in future releases. Any idea?

Comment: I'd also like to know when this will be possible. News anyone?